# Version match with cloudera Hbase and Titan

Tags: apache, hbase, cloudera, titan

I'm running hbase-0.94.6-cdh4.5.0 on ubuntu 12.04 as standalone. Could anyone let me know which version of Titan is used for best fit.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the Release notes in the Titan DB WIKI page: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Release-Notes

The HBase version 0.94.6 is not mentioned but Titan 0.3.2 did support 0.94.1 and the next one did support 0.94.7... so I would suggest to give a try to those.